# Number of arrangements

Tags: algorithm, math

Suppose we have *n* elements, *a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *a*<sub>n</sub>, arranged in a circle. That is, *a*<sub>2</sub> is between *a*<sub>1</sub> and *a*<sub>3</sub>, *a*<sub>3</sub> is between *a*<sub>2</sub> and *a*<sub>4</sub>, *a*<sub>*n*</sub> is between *a*<sub>*n*-1</sub> and *a*<sub>1</sub>, and so forth.

Each element can take the value of either 1 or 0. Two arrangements are different if there are corresponding *a*<sub>*i*</sub>'s whose values differ. For instance, when *n*=3, (1, 0, 0) and (0, 1, 0) are different arrangements, even though they may be isomorphic under rotation or reflection.

Because there are *n* elements, each of which can take two values, the total number of arrangements is 2<sup>*n*</sup>.

**Here is the question:**

How many arrangements are possible, such that no two adjacent elements both have the value 1? If it helps, only consider cases where *n*>3.

I ask here for several reasons:

1. This arose while I was solving a programming problem
2. It sounds like the problem may benefit from Boolean logic/bit arithmetic
3. Maybe there is no closed solution.

Comment: Just to clarify, the circle comes in to the definition of what it means to be adjacent -- element n is adjacent to element 1 -- but you do not consider rotations of the same bit pattern to be the same.  Is that right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's first ask the question "how many 0-1 sequences of length n are there with no two consecutive 1s?" Let the answer be A(n). We have A(0)=1 (the empty sequence), A(1) = 2 ("0" and "1"), and A(2)=3 ("00", "01" and "10" but not "11").

To make it easier to write a recurrence, we'll compute A(n) as the sum of two numbers:
B(n), the number of such sequences that end with a 0, and
C(n), the number of such sequences that end with a 1.

Then B(n) = A(n-1) (take any such sequence of length n-1, and append a 0)
and C(n) = B(n-1) (because if you have a 1 at position n, you must have a 0 at n-1.)
This gives A(n) = B(n) + C(n) = A(n-1) + B(n-1) = A(n-1) + A(n-2).
By now it should be familiar :-)

A(n) is simply the Fibonacci number F<sub>n+2</sub> where the Fibonacci sequence is defined by
 F<sub>0</sub>=0, F<sub>1</sub>=1, and F<sub>n+2</sub>= F<sub>n+1</sub>+F<sub>n</sub> for n ≥ 0.

Now for your question. We'll count the number of arrangements with a<sub>1</sub>=0 and a<sub>1</sub>=1 separately. For the former, a<sub>2</sub> … a<sub>n</sub> can be any sequence at all (with no consecutive 1s), so the number is A(n-1)=F<sub>n+1</sub>. For the latter, we must have a<sub>2</sub>=0, and then a<sub>3</sub>…a<sub>n</sub> is any sequence with no consecutive 1s that *ends with a 0*, i.e. B(n-2)=A(n-3)=F<sub>n-1</sub>.

So **the answer is F<sub>n+1</sub> + F<sub>n-1</sub>.**

<sub>Actually, we can go even further than that answer. Note that if you call the answer as
 G(n)=F<sub>n+1</sub>+F<sub>n-1</sub>, then 

G(n+1)=F<sub>n+2</sub>+F<sub>n</sub>, and 

G(n+2)=F<sub>n+3</sub>+F<sub>n+1</sub>, so even G(n) satisfies the same recurrence as the Fibonacci sequence! [Actually, any linear combination of Fibonacci-like sequences will satisfy the same recurrence, so it's not all that surprising.] So another way to compute the answers would be using:

G(2)=3

G(3)=4

G(n)=G(n-1)+G(n-2) for n≥4.</sub>

And now you can also use the [closed form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) F<sub>n</sub>=(α<sup>n</sup>-β<sup>n</sup>)/(α-β) (where α and β are (1±√5)/2, the roots of x<sup>2</sup>-x-1=0), to get 
**G(n) = ((1+√5)/2)<sup>n</sup> + ((1-√5)/2)<sup>n</sup>.**
[You can ignore the second term because it's very close to 0 for large n, in fact G(n) is the **closest integer to ((1+√5)/2)<sup>n</sup>** for all n≥2.]

Comment: Checks by hand against 2, 3, 4. I think that the argument about constructing B(n) and C(n) force the correctness of the ends by deduction from the two cases of length 1.

Comment: See "For the latter, we must have a2=0, and then a3…an is any sequence with no consecutive 1s *that ends with a 0*" -- that's where I consider that the sequence cannot both begin and end in 1.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to hack up a small script to try it out:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

# thx google 
bstr_pos = lambda n: n>0 and bstr_pos(n>>1)+str(n&1) or ""

def arrangements(n):
    count = 0
    for v in range(0, pow(2,n)-1):
        bin = bstr_pos(v).rjust(n, '0')
        if not ( bin.find("11")!=-1 or ( bin[0]=='1' and bin[-1]=='1' ) ):
            count += 1
            print bin
    print "Total = " + str(count)

arrangements(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Running this for 5, gave me a total of 11 possibilities with 00000,
00001,
00010,
00100,
00101,
01000,
01001,
01010,
10000,
10010,
10100.

P.S. - Excuse the not() in the above code.

Comment: Great confirmation of "theory" (the other answer), because F(6)=8 and F(4)=3, so G(5)=F(6)+F(4) is indeed 11 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my naive script into the mix. Plenty of opportunity for caching partial results, but it ran fast enough for small n that I didn't bother.

```
def arcCombinations(n, lastDigitMustBeZero):
    """Takes the length of the remaining arc of the circle, and computes
       the number of legal combinations.
       The last digit may be restricted to 0 (because the first digit is a 1)"""

    if n == 1: 
        if lastDigitMustBeZero:
            return 1 # only legal answer is 0
        else:
            return 2 # could be 1 or 0.
    elif n == 2:
        if lastDigitMustBeZero:
            return 2 # could be 00 or 10
        else:
            return 3 # could be 10, 01 or 00
    else:
        # Could be a 1, in which case next item is a zero.
        return (
            arcCombinations(n-2, lastDigitMustBeZero) # If it starts 10
            + arcCombinations(n-1, lastDigitMustBeZero) # If it starts 0
            )

def circleCombinations(n):
    """Computes the number of legal combinations for a given circle size."""

    # Handle case where it starts with 0 or with 1.
    total = (
            arcCombinations(n-1,True) # Number of combinations where first digit is a 1.
            +
            arcCombinations(n-1,False) # Number of combinations where first digit is a 0.
        )
    return total


print circleCombinations(13)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very similar to [Zeckendorf representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem).  I can't find an obvious way to apply Zeckendorf's Theorem, due to the circularity constraint, but the Fibonacci numbers are obviously very prevalent in this problem.